# tabwidget divder in tabwidget disappear when tabwidget background is set from code?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget, divider

divider in tabWidget is working fine but when background of tab widget is set like

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabId).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);
```

problem is how to set divider in tab widget after setting background
though i used

```
tabhost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_widget_divider);
```

is does not work for multiple tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There may be multiple reasons for the dividers not showing up...

**1. setDividerDrawable() must be used before you add the tabs to the tabHost to work.**

**2. By default there's are -2(left), -2(right) margins set to each tabindicator's View...**

By default the system is using 9-patch drawables for tabWidget backgrounds with at least 2 pixels left transparent(or semi-transparent for shadow-effect) to the left and the right side.

[image: my custom tab example]

*1. demonstration*

---

[image: original system 9-path drawable in android 2.3.3 (selected)][image]

*2. Stock 9-path drawables for tab widget background. You can use these for experimenting*

---

**If you don't wan't to use 9-path drawables...**
you can set the margins to 0 to prevent the tab views overlapping your divider. Here's the code:

```
    View v;
    int count = tw.getTabCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        v = tw.getChildTabViewAt(i);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_tab);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```